# Ad-Hoc distributed app does not installing on device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I am signing my app for the ad-Hoc distribution. I have created certificate and Provisioning profile and also checked the device UDID.

But when i first time create distribution certificate and sign the app with that certificate and appropriate Provisioning profile than app works.

But when i use same Certificate and Provisioning profile for second time app doesn't work. its displaying grey out icon on device and iTunes display installing.. in app.

I have checked my crash log and this is printed

```
.................
..................
Apr  7 20:17:19 Dilip-Maneks-iPad librariand[114] <Error>: ubiquity account is not configured (or is disabled for this client), not creating collection
Apr  7 20:17:19 Dilip-Maneks-iPad librariand[114] <Error>: error in _handle_client_request: LibrarianErrorDomain/10/Unable to configure the collection.
Apr  7 20:17:19 Dilip-Maneks-iPad geod[94] <Warning>: Can't get bundle identifier for process 424
Apr  7 20:17:23 Dilip-Maneks-iPad mobileassetd[107] <Error>: mobileassetd - _ASAssetDeletionPriorityAtDate: Unexpected value for keys __LastAccessDate, __InstallDate
Apr  7 20:17:23 Dilip-Maneks-iPad mobileassetd[107] <Error>: mobileassetd - _ASAssetDeletionPriorityAtDate: Unexpected value for keys __LastAccessDate, __InstallDate
Apr  7 20:17:23 Dilip-Maneks-iPad medialibraryd[93] <Warning>: {MediaLibrary} [MLWriter] ending transaction <__NSConcreteUUID 0x124530320> 7B9EAD03-51E8-4DE5-AF91-ECE8BBABA5E0. shouldCommit=0.
Apr  7 20:17:23 Dilip-Maneks-iPad librariand[114] <Error>: ubiquity account is not configured (or is disabled for this client), not creating collection
Apr  7 20:17:23 Dilip-Maneks-iPad librariand[114] <Error>: error in _handle_client_request: LibrarianErrorDomain/10/Unable to configure the collection.
Apr  7 20:17:23 Dilip-Maneks-iPad deleted[424] <Error>: 0x100484000 __DeleteLibrarian_block_invoke: unable to determine evictable space: The operation couldn’t be completed. (LibrarianErrorDomain error 10 - Unable to configure the collection.)
Apr  7 20:17:29 Dilip-Maneks-iPad librariand[114] <Error>: ubiquity account is not configured (or is disabled for this client), not creating collection
Apr  7 20:17:29 Dilip-Maneks-iPad librariand[114] <Error>: error in _handle_client_request: LibrarianErrorDomain/10/Unable to configure the collection.
Apr  7 20:17:29 Dilip-Maneks-iPad atc[1020] <Warning>: {MediaLibrary} Database validation succeeded
Apr  7 20:17:29 Dilip-Maneks-iPad librariand[114] <Error>: ubiquity account is not configured (or is disabled for this client), not creating collection
Apr  7 20:17:29 Dilip-Maneks-iPad librariand[114] <Error>: error in _handle_client_request: LibrarianErrorDomain/10/Unable to configure the collection.
Apr  7 20:17:29 Dilip-Maneks-iPad geod[94] <Warning>: Can't get bundle identifier for process 424
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered something similar - in iTunes the status was stuck on "Installing..." and similarly on the phone the app had a disabled icon and would not launch.

The solution in my case was to correct the "Team" identity in Xcode (Target > General > Identity > Team) and choose a valid iOS Distribution certificate (set up at https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateList.action). I had inadvertently left this setting as "None". This certificate must be the one referenced in the "Distribution" iOS Provisioning Profile that you choose after archiving, in the Organizer window of Xcode.

Only when everything matches will your ad hoc app install & launch. See the bottom of this page:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

under the section titled "Ad Hoc Provisioning Profiles in Depth"